# In grep on Ubuntu, how can I display only the string that matched the regular expression?

Tags: ubuntu, grep

I am basically grepping with a regular expression on. In the output, I would like to see only the strings that match my reg exp.

In a bunch of XML files (mostly they are single-line files with huge amounts of data in a line), I would like to get all the words that start with *MAIL_*.

Also, I would like the grep command on the shell to give only the words that matched and not the entire line (which is the entire file in this case).

How do I do this?

I have tried

```
grep -Gril MAIL_* .
grep -Grio MAIL_* .
grep -Gro MAIL_* .
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First of all, with GNU grep that is installed with Ubuntu, -G flag (use basic regexp) is the default, so you can omit it, but, even better, use extended regexp with -E.

-r flag means recursive search within files of a directory, this is what you need.

And, you are right to use -o flag to print matching part of a line. Also, to omit file names you will need a -h flag.

The only mistake you made is the regular expression itself. You missed character specification before *. Your command should look like this:

```
grep -Ehro 'MAIL_[^[:space:]]*' .
```

Sample output (not recursive):

```
$ echo "Some garbage MAIL_OPTION comes MAIL_VALUE here" | grep -Eho 'MAIL_[^[:space:]]*'
MAIL_OPTION
MAIL_VALUE
```

Comment: great..that works, but one quick question

how do i do if i know the MAIL_* stuff are either present as
type="MAIL_*"   or >MAIL_*<  in the files?
any help on that one?

Comment: I don't get it. Could you rephrase your question?
You want to see surrounding characters around your MAIL_XXX stuff?
Like, you want to see " and <> in output of grep command?

Comment: if your MAIL_* could only contain alphabetic characters (a-z), then you can change regexp to 'MAIL_[[:alpha:]]*'

Answer (score 6):

Try the following command

```
grep -Eo 'MAIL_[[:alnum:]_]*'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -o or --only-matching
```

outputs only the matching text instead of complete lines but the problem could be your regex that's not restrictive or greedy enough and actually matches the whole file.

Comment: now the type of words i want are present like this in the file

type="MAIL_ABC_CDE"
type="MAIL_XXX_AAA_AAA"
etc

there can be any number of _'s
WHat should be the reg exp i shoudl use? any idea on that?

Answer (score 0):

From your comment to Thor's answer it seems you also want to distinguish if the `MAIL_.*` text is a text node or an attribute, not just to isolate it whenever it appears in the XML document. Grep cannot parse XML, [you need a proper XML parser for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

A command line xml parser is [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/). It is packaged in Ubuntu.

Using it on this example file example file:

```
$ cat test.xml 
<some_root>
    <test a="MAIL_as_attribute">will be printed if you want matching attributes</test>
    <bar>MAIL_as_text will be printed if you want matching text nodes</bar>
    <MAIL_will_not_be_printed>abc</MAIL_will_not_be_printed>
</some_root>
```

For selecting text nodes you can use:

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//*' -v 'text()' -n test.xml | grep -Eo 'MAIL_[^[:space:]]*'
MAIL_as_text
```

And for selecting attributes:

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//*[@*]' -v '@*' -n test.xml | grep -Eo 'MAIL_[^[:space:]]*'
MAIL_as_attribute
```

Brief explanations:

- `//*` is an XPath expression that selects all elements in the document and `text()` outputs the value of their children text nodes, therefore everything except text nodes gets filtered out
- `//*[@*]` is an XPath expression that selects all attributes in the document and then `@*` outputs their value